# Copy files sequential with 60s queue in powershell

Tags: powershell

The task is to copy files from one directory to another:

```
Copy-Item $source\*.pdf -Destination $target
```

The difficulty is that they should be copied sequentially, but each with a Time Offset of 60 seconds. Is there any way I can do this with PowerShell?

I am grateful for any help.
Greetings, Irmi

Comment: You just need a loop and `Start-Sleep` :)

Comment: TY. that sounds like a good approach. I'll try :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Start-Sleep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/start-sleep) to wait in between copy operations in a loop:

```
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem path\to\source\folder -Filter *.pdf){
  # Wait 60s 
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
  # Copy file
  $file |Copy-Item -Destination path\to\destination\folder
}
```

Comment: Perfect! It works like a charme :-) Many thx, Mathias!